# Global Socket connection

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I'm creating a Server-Client application and I'm using windows form applications in c# to do so.
My problem comes in the client, I have many forms (Views) and I need to maintain a connection to the server when I switch views (windows). I created a class to hold the global variables , but the connection I have no idea how to maintain. I'm using TCP sockets, I'll post my `globalVariables` class:

```
static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    public static IPEndPoint newPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6000);
    public static int msgRec = 0;
    public static String msgConverted ="";
    public static byte[] data = new byte[1024];


    public static void receiveMsgFromServer()
    {
        msgRec = client.Receive(data); //metodo que retorna o numero de bytes da mensagem (recebe o array de bytes)
        msgConverted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, msgRec); //metodo que converte os bytes em string
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(msgConverted);
    }

    public static void connect()
    {
        client.Connect(newPoint);
    }
  }
}


class MultiThreadedTcpServer
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        //Servidor TCP

        Socket newSocket = new Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);//server
        IPEndPoint newPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6000); //ponto de acesso no port 6000 para todos os endereços de IP da maquina
        newSocket.Bind(newPoint);//associar o ponto de acesso ao socket
        newSocket.Listen(10); 
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting..."); 

        //Cliente - definir o comportamente para com o cliente
        Socket client;
        sharedData counter = new sharedData(); // este objecto é passado por referencia para as outras classes logo estes olham todos para o mesmo
        while (true)
        {
            client = newSocket.Accept(); // socket usado para comunicar com o cliente (NAO É O CLIENTE !!!!!!)
            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint; // informacao sobre o ponto de acesso do cliente
            Console.WriteLine(remoteEndPoint +" " + "Connected"); // escreve esta linha na consola do programa para o admin saber que houve uma conexao

            //criar uma thread para cada novo cliente passando-lhe a respectiva ligacao remota
            ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(client, remoteEndPoint, counter); //nos parametros passamos o socket do client e o endpoint do cliente
            counter.clientes.Add(client);
            Thread t = new Thread (new ThreadStart(clientHandler.clientProc));
            t.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

Sorry about the portuguese comments. The goal is to have many clients connected to one server (thats why i have threads) that all works ok.
Now my problem is, I load the `GlobalVariables.Connect();` when I start my client app, but when I switch views I lose the connections. Any tips?

Comment: please add the server connection code

Comment: I just did. I think my problem is just in the graphical interface, because i can make everything work in console mode. I just need to be able to switch from one view to another while keeping the connection.

Comment: In your code, we don't see any links between GlobalVariables class and the Main method. Is it supposed to be in the Client app ? By the way, we have nothing about how your Client app and Server app manages the threads. If there is a GUI, Sockets should be run in another thread than the main thread so you can keep connections seperate from the GUI and so on, not lose any connection by a timeout or else.

Comment: My globalVariables is from the client app and that main is from the server. I just need to be able, e.g. (in the client app) Im in window "Form1" and i connect to the server , then i press OK , "Form1" closes and "Form2" opens. but when form1 closes, the connection to the server closes aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what i wanted. I created another Static class that handles the connection , and all the other views just ask that class whenever they need something from the server. This way i only need to have 1 connnections and all the other views on my application send data to that class and then that class communicates directly with the server.